# How to hide first name in citation call-out (apalike bib style, natbib package)

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm using:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
```

and

```
\bibliography{mybib}
```

I have the following reference:

```
@article{svdcomp,
    Author = {{M. Holmes et al.}},
    Title = {Fast {SVD} for large-scale matrices.},
    Lastchecked = {February 16, 2018},
    journal =  {Workshop on Efficient Machine Learning at NIPS},
    volume = {58},
    pages={249--252},
    Year = {2007}}
```

I would like for this to appear as [Holmes et al., 2007] when using `\citep{svdcomp}`. However, it appears as [M. Holmes et al., 2007]. How do I remove the "M." from appearing in the citation call-out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `author` field

```
Author = {{M. Holmes et al.}},
```

contains two mistakes. The first mistake is the use of a double rather than a single pair of curly braces to enclose the field. The double pair fools BibTeX into thinking that it's dealing with a single, "corporate" author named, you guessed it, "M. Holmes et al." If you look closely in the formatted bibliography, you'll find that entry is sorted under "M" and not under "H".

The second mistake is "et al". Change it to "and others". BibTeX will then automatically translate it to "et al" in both the citation call-out and the formatted bibliographic entry.

To sum up: If you change the author field to

```
Author = {M. Holmes and others},
```

the citation call-out generated by `\citep` will be

> [Homes et al., 2007]

which is what you're looking for, right?

Better still, change the `author` field to list *all* authors, including their full first names:

```
Author = {Michael P. Holmes and Alexander G. Gray and Charles Lee Isbell},
```

That way, the citation call-out will still be `[Homes et al., 2007]`, but the formatted bibliographic entry will show all three authors.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with your previous answer but now with "and others" it works just as I want it to. Thanks a lot and have a good weekend!